# RecyclerView doesn't update in onBackPressed

Tags: android

I would like to develop a file manager for Android but I have a problem. I can show the files and navigate through directories, so I've overrided onBackPressed() for return to previous directory (using a stack for store the navigation history). The problem is that the RecyclerView isn't updating. The weird thing is that I've used almost the same code for both enter directories (that works) and leave.
onBackPressed override method:

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if(pathStack.size()>1) {
        currentDir = new File(pathStack.pop());
        setupData(currentDir); //method to list all the files
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    else
        super.onBackPressed();

}
```

in setupData method, I add history to the stack this way:

```
pathStack.push(getCurrentPath());
```

Finally this is the code I use to navigate the directories (works well):

```
adapter.setOnFileClickedListener(new FileAdapter.onFileClickedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFileClick(String newPath) {
            currentDir=new File(newPath);
            setupData(currentDir);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

this is the complete setupData() method:

```
public void setupData(File f) {
    pathStack.push(getCurrentPath());
    File[] dirs = f.listFiles();
    this.setTitle(f.getName());
    dir = new ArrayList<Item>();
    fls = new ArrayList<Item>();


    try {
        for (File ff : dirs) {
            Date lastModDate = new Date(ff.lastModified());
            DateFormat formater = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
            String date_modify = formater.format(lastModDate);
            if (ff.isDirectory()) {
                File[] dirFls = ff.listFiles();
                int buf = 0;
                if (dirFls != null) {
                    buf = dirFls.length;
                } else buf = 0;
                String num_item = String.valueOf(buf);
                if (buf==1)
                    num_item = num_item + " item";
                else
                    num_item = num_item + " items";
                dir.add(new Item(ff.getName(), num_item, date_modify, ff.getAbsolutePath(), "directory_icon"));
            } else {
                fls.add(new Item(ff.getName(), ff.length() + " Byte", date_modify, ff.getAbsolutePath(), "file_icon"));
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    Collections.sort(dir);
    Collections.sort(fls);
    dir.addAll(fls);
    setupAdapter();


}
```

and

```
private void setupAdapter() {
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    adapter = new FileAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.recycler_row, dir);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    adapter.setOnFileClickedListener(new FileAdapter.onFileClickedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFileClick(String newPath) {
            currentDir=new File(newPath);
            setupData(currentDir);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: I cannot see any changes in adapter data. So where You change data in adapter?

Comment: In setupData() I list all the files of the new current directory, then I have a method setupAdapter that pass this list to the adapter.

Comment: There must be problem, paste it

Comment: edited, check the question above